# How to read XML data and parse into staging table in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

Can anyone let me know how to parse below XML data to load into staging table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FIXML r="20030618" s="20040109" v="5.0" xr="FIA" xv="1" xmlns="NA">
  <Batch BizDt="2019-10-22" TotMsg="47150">
    <PosMntReq ReqID="1" TxnTyp="4" AdjTyp="4" Actn="1" BizDt="2019-10-21" SetSesID="EOD" TxnTm="2019-10-22T17:40:01">
      <Instrmt Exch="ERT" SecTyp="TPY" ID="BTR" MMY="201912"/>
      <Qty Typ="TQ" Long="18" Short="10"/>
    </PosMntReq>
</Batch>
</FIXML>
```

I want to read data from PosMntReq  and load everything that is in that tag and then read next tag Instrmt  and load into table.

### EDIT

Is there any way I can update

```
<<FIXML r="20030618" s="20040109" v="5.0" xr="FIA" xv="1" xmlns="NA">
```

with

```
<FIXML>..
```

The value inside FIXML will not always be same. Similarly, If I can update

```
<Batch BizDt="2019-10-22" TotMsg="47150">
```

with

```
<Batch>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can update <<FIXML r="20030618" s="20040109" v="5.0" xr="FIA" xv="1" xmlns="NA"> with <FIXML>..The value inside FIXML will not always be same. Similarly, If I can update <Batch BizDt="2019-10-22" TotMsg="47150"> with <Batch>.

Comment: Please don't "add" information to your question using comments. It's very likely that people will answer your question without reading the comments. Instead, **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags to include additional information. I've done it for you this time, but keep this in mind for your next question. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of gaps in your question. Where does the XML fragment come from? A file? A variable? A database column? What programming language(s) are you using? What is the expected output after you "load everything in a table"?